# Why can't I render "place_id" in google maps api to an ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ejs

I am rendering maps.ejs file with : place_id , lat , lng .

If I declare the "place_id" in the maps.ejs file in initMap function itself then the code is running fine without any errors.
But when I render the place_id as shown in the code it gives error in chrome's console :

(index):34 Uncaught ReferenceError: ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4 is not defined
    at initMap ((index):34)

I am using cloud9 and have exported API_KEY as an environment variable.

```js
//app.js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("maps.ejs", {
    place_id: "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
    lat: -33.8666199,
    lng: 151.1958527
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log("Server is ON");
}); // Server start
```

```html
//maps.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<title>Google Maps API</title>

<body>
  <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var uluru = {
        lat: <%=lat%>,
        lng: <%=lng%>
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: uluru
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      service.getDetails({
        placeId: <%=place_id%>
      }, function(place, status) {
        console.log(place);
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(
              '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
              'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
              place.formatted_address + '<br>' +
              "Rating : " + place.rating + '</div>');
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
        }
      });
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%=process.env.API_KEY%>&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
  </script>
  <div id="map"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Maps API is a **web browser** API. You're just setting yourself up for trouble if you think in terms of debugging it as part of your Express server app.

Instead, look at the generated code *in the browser*, either with View Source or using the browser's developer tools. This will simplify your debugging considerably. The server code is completely irrelevant once the generated HTML and JavaScript code hits the browser.

That said, the particular error you ran into is very likely due to this line of code in your `maps.ejs` file:

```
    placeId: <%=place_id%>
```

As you will see when you do a View Source in the browser, the code generated by Express here is probably:

```
    placeId: ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4
```

In other words, JavaScript in the browser sees `ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4` as a *variable name*, not as the literal string you probably need here.

To fix this, simply put the ID in quotes:

```
    placeId: "<%=place_id%>"
```

Now the generated code will be:

```
    placeId: "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4"
```

And now `placeId` will be a string as expected.

Comment: I tried creating a string variable place_id but that too wasn't working. 
My bad ... Thankyou very much ..
It was a silly question.

Comment: Not a silly question at all. And don't feel bad - this happens to all of us at one time or another! The reason I spotted it so fast is that I've made the same mistake myself. ;-) Do let me know if this turned out to be the problem.